# CMake CTest prevent truncation of test name

Tags: cmake, truncation, css, ctest

I'm currently running CTest, but I have a problem whereby tests with long names.  For example:

```
"API Part1 : Some test information w/ this input file"
```

get's truncated to something like

```
"API Part1 : Some test information w/ th").
```

It seems like the test name is truncated to about 31 characters.  How can I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--max-width <width>: Set the max width for a test name to output
```

Set the maximum width for each test name to show in the output. This allows the user to widen the output to avoid cliping the test name which can be very annoying.

This option is available for **2.8** Versions

Comment: I don't see a 2.6.8.  There's 2.6.4 and 2.8.  Presumably this is a 2.8 feature?